# how to correctly split the following string ? - Python

Tags: python, parsing

I have the following file to be parsed:

```
Total Virtual Clients       :             10      (1 Machines)
Current Connections         :             10
Total Elapsed Time          :             50 Secs (0 Hrs,0 Mins,50 Secs)

Total Requests              :         337827      (    6687/Sec)
Total Responses             :         337830      (    6687/Sec)
Total Bytes                 :      990388848      (   20571 KB/Sec)
Total Success Connections   :           3346      (      66/Sec)
Total Connect Errors        :              0      (       0/Sec)
Total Socket Errors         :              0      (       0/Sec)
Total I/O Errors            :              0      (       0/Sec)
Total 200 OK                :          33864      (     718/Sec)
Total 30X Redirect          :              0      (       0/Sec)
Total 304 Not Modified      :              0      (       0/Sec)
Total 404 Not Found         :         303966      (    5969/Sec)
Total 500 Server Error      :              0      (       0/Sec)
Total Bad Status            :         303966      (    5969/Sec)
```

so I have the parsing algorithm to search the files for those values, however, when I do:

```
for data in temp:
     line = data.strip().split()
     print line
```

where `temp` is my temporary buffer, which contains those values, 
I get:

```
['Total', 'I/O', 'Errors', ':', '0', '(', '0/Sec)']
['Total', '200', 'OK', ':', '69807', '(', '864/Sec)']
['Total', '30X', 'Redirect', ':', '0', '(', '0/Sec)']
['Total', '304', 'Not', 'Modified', ':', '0', '(', '0/Sec)']
['Total', '404', 'Not', 'Found', ':', '420953', '(', '5289/Sec)']
['Total', '500', 'Server', 'Error', ':', '0', '(', '0/Sec)']
```

and I wanted:

```
['Total I/O Errors', '0', '0']
['Total 200 OK', '69807', '864']
['Total 30X Redirect', '0', '0']
```

and so on.
How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) as follows:

```
import re
rex = re.compile('([^:]+\S)\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*\(\s*(\d+)/Sec\)')
for line in temp:
    match = rex.match(line)
    if match:
        print match.groups()
```

which will give you:

```
['Total Requests', '337827', '6687']
['Total Responses', '337830', '6687']
['Total Success Connections', '3346', '66']
['Total Connect Errors', '0', '0']
['Total Socket Errors', '0', '0']
['Total I/O Errors', '0', '0']
['Total 200 OK', '33864', '718']
['Total 30X Redirect', '0', '0']
['Total 304 Not Modified', '0', '0']
['Total 404 Not Found', '303966', '5969']
['Total 500 Server Error', '0', '0']
['Total Bad Status', '303966', '5969']
```

Note that will only match lines which correspond to "TITLE:NUMBER(NUMBER/Sec)". You can adapt the expression to match the other lines as well.

Comment: That's cool man! Thank you! ( will accept your answer in a few )

Answer (score 1):

regular expressions are overkill for parsing your data, but it is a convenient way to express the fixed length fields. For example

```
for data in temp:
    first, second, third = re.match("(.{28}):(.{21})(.*)", data).groups()
    ...
```

This means the first field is 28 chars. Skip the ':', next 21 chars is second field, remainder is the 3rd field

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting on whitespace, you will need to split based on the other delimiters in your format, it might look something like this:

```
for data in temp:
     first, rest = data.split(':')
     second, rest = rest.split('(')
     third, rest = rest.split(')')
     print [x.strip() for x in (first, second, third)]
```

Comment: The data appears to be fixed field width, so it would be better to use fixed slicing